# The significance of the 'Star' in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, etymology

I understand that Star Wars, like many outer-space sci-fi's includes a variety of planets and moons to set much of the space action around:

- Space battle around Endor
- Space battle arround Yavin and Yavin IV
- Attack on Coruscant
- etc

Obviously Star Wars was focused around a number of wars i.e. Trade War, Clone War, Rebellion so why is it that the saga was not named Space Wars (obviously this was trademarked), Planet and Moon Wars, Galactic Wars or something similar? Why would the 'Star' in Star Wars be significant? 
I do not recall any specific star being a location for any trilogy or prequel setting, instead star **systems** were more important, specifically planets and their moons.
Was it the cash-in effect from 'Star' Trek?

Maybe i'm just missing a reference or quote from some canon or Lucas material which describes the title.

Comment: Stars are the fundamental (visible) structural components of galaxies. Hence "Star Wars" -> wars among the stars -> wars in space. I really don't think there's anything more to it.

Comment: Star rhymes with war?

Comment: There’s lots of space where there aren’t any stars, and while you could have a war there, it’s a) a bloody long way from all the planets that the people having the war live on, and b) a bit pointless, because no-one really wants control of empty space millions of miles away from any stars.

Comment: And — most importantly — it sounds cooler. Is Harrison Ford called an actor in films or a professional pretending person? Nope. He’s called a movie star. Was the third Bond movie called Criminal Precious Metal Magnate? Nope. It was called *Goldfinger*. That’s *showbiz*, honey.

Comment: @Dunebro Depends on your accent.  They don't rhyme when I say them.

Comment: I've not heard of any explanation as to how the name was chosen.  I suspect that the name was evocative and simple enough that it'd catch peoples attention, back before science fiction movies really took off.

They were great days, as long as you liked detective fiction...

Comment: What's with all the down-votes! See: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/what-does-punk-in-steampunk-mean. Pretty much the same format question!

Comment: @Mothermole1 - probably people considered it "too trivial". +1 since I think it's a perfectly valid question, to offset the DVs

Comment: In Spanish it actually is called “La Guerra de las Galaxias” = “Galactic War”

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Star" was used in the colloquial meaning of "inter**stellar**", as in "in space". See also "Starship" (it's not ship to go to a specific star) for similar usage.